# Maintaining separate environments with no downtime on update in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have been tweaking my environment in Google's App Engine to have several instances of my app for testing and production. However I am uncertain if the intended use of versions applies here.

App background:
 - Node.js express app configured on app engine, using Cloud sql.
 - 2 modules:
 - - default/main - front end code code and API
 - - workers - separate app that has a variety of workers
- Redis to keep track of the queue, kue.js for implementation

I was under the impression that I could use versions here, so that I keep only 2 modules, my default one and a workers module. Each will then have 2 versions, staging and production. The commands to push each one would then be:

```
gcloud preview app deploy --version staging --no-promote
gcloud preview app deploy --version production --promote --no-stop-previous-version
```

That is all separated well, and perhaps the intended use of versions. However, what I can't achieve with this is no downtime. **What seems to happen is that the old machine is tore down then the new one build up, resulting in 3-4 minutes of down time during deploys.** As opposed to keeping the old until the new is finished and then just rerouting. Note, the production version in this case should always have 100% of the traffic.

What I found to work well is to keep a module for each version, so I end up with 4 modules (default, default-staging, workers, workers-staging) and no real versions specified during deploys. When deploying with this, there is no downtime, but old versions are kept running:

```
gcloud preview app deploy --promote
```

I have a helper script to delete all versions that get 0% of the traffic. Is this the correct approach for setting up separate environments? Just looking for some feedback in case I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I think create a separate app is better. Even though version isolate code, but the underlying infrastructure like datastore, memcache still shared. This could be problematic if you change something like the model definition and the changes is not backward compatible.